# Render HTML in Google Docs Viewer Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-docs-api

I'm trying to render HTML in Google Docs Spreadsheet. The file is shown perfectly fine when seen locally in Excel. But when the same file uploaded on the drive and seen by Google Docs the HTML markup is shown in the spreadsheet. Tried to find the parameters of URI to render HTML but didn't find any. Below is the block of code while uploading the file to drive in C#.

```
    {
        GoogleConnect.ClientId = "<CLient ID>";
        GoogleConnect.ClientSecret = "<Client Secret>";
        GoogleConnect.RedirectUri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Split('?')[0];
        GoogleConnect.API = EnumAPI.Drive;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["code"]))
        {
            string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
            string json = GoogleConnect.PostFile(code, (HttpPostedFile)Session["File"], Session["Description"].ToString());

            GoogleDriveFile file = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<GoogleDriveFile>(json);
            tblFileDetails.Visible = true;
            lblTitle.Text = file.Title;
            lblId.Text = file.Id;
            imgIcon.ImageUrl = file.IconLink;
            lblCreatedDate.Text = file.CreatedDate.ToString();
            lnkDownload.NavigateUrl = file.WebContentLink;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.ThumbnailLink))
            {
                rowThumbnail.Visible = true;
                imgThumbnail.ImageUrl = file.ThumbnailLink;
            }
        }
    }


I expect the Google Docs Spreadsheet show the HTML in a proper way and not the HTML markup. Thanks.
```